# Limitar data fim de acordo com data inicial no bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Gostaria de saber como faço para limitar a data final do formulário utilizando datepicker, preciso que quando seja selecionado no calendário a data inicial, a final automaticamente limite para até 90 dias. Já pesquisei e não encontrei nada do tipo. Segue abaixo os meus campos html:

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="input-group date dataIni" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="date" class="form-control inputIni">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group date dataFim" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="date" class="form-control inputFim">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Os calendários funcionam corretamente, o formato tem que ser dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('inputIni').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'pt-br',
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

$('.inputFim').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'pt-br',
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  useCurrent: false
});

$(".inputIni").on("dp.change", function (e) {
   $('.inputFim').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date.add(90,'days'));
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas no meu caso estou utilizando o datepicker Bootstrap (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Tentei alterar os parâmetros utilizando seu exemplo mas não deu em nada. :(